# VBA/Access: How to stop "You... FORM to be active window"

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I want to be able to tell IF a form is the active window.

It seems simply invoking that method produces an error. I guess I could catch that error and run with it, but it's a backwards way of doing it.

`Screen.ActiveForm.Name`

This needs a form to be active. If I am breaking any rules of stackOverflow please be kind and remind me as I am new to forum.

Screen.parent, screen.activeControl, etc. What if VBA editor is open, as often it is?

```
Function CStatus(strStatus, ByRef intType As Integer, Optional ByRef erNo, Optional erMsg, Optional strDatum)
'pXname = "CStatus"
'pXStack = Left(pXStack, 500) & ">" & pXname
'Updates and manages the status bar

Dim strPreamble As String, strOut As String, strForm As String, strComment As String, strSQL As String, strPxStack As String, strCErrStack As String
Dim intColor As Double
Dim intPreLen As Integer

'On Error GoTo err_hand


'Color Codes
'12632256 = Lt Grey
'33023 = Orange
'65280 = Green
'16744576 = Steel Grey

'Define "Constants"
intPreLen = 350 'Length of previous message cache

'** Fix missings
    If (IsMissing(strDatum) = True) Then strDatum = "[N/A]"

'** Other inits
strWindow = Screen.Parent.Name

strForm = Screen.ActiveForm.Name

'** intDebug ' Minimum Level of to report to status
'bEcho = True 'Whether to echo to status

intColor = errNoColor(intType)

'Error-level idiot explanations
strComment = "0"
    If IsMissing(erNo) Then erNo = 0
   If (IsNull(erMsg) = False) Then
   If IsMissing(erMsg) = False Then strComment = erMsg
   End If


strComment = errorTree(erNo)

strPreamble = Left(strPreamble, intPreLen) & "..."
strErrStack = Left(strErrStack, intPreLen) & " > " & pXname & ":" & intType
strCErrStack = strErrStack

reS:

If ((strForm = "finvmain") Or (strForm = "fclips")) Then Screen.ActiveForm.timeStatusUpdated = Now() 'Small field keeps time

If bEcho = True Then
    strPxStack = ""
    strCErrStack = "" 'Internal error stack
    End If

strOut = Now() & " " & intType & " (" & strType & "): " & erNo & " " & strCErrStack & " >> " & strComment & " / " & strStatus & " [" & strDatum & "] .. " & strPreamble

    If bEcho = True Then
    If (strForm = "fInvMain") Then Screen.ActiveForm.txtStatus2 = Screen.ActiveForm.txtStatus 'Added second window to show previous message
        Screen.ActiveForm.txtStatus = strOut
        End If

Screen.ActiveForm.txtStatus.ForeColor = intColor
If strForm = "fInvMain" Then strTag = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls("txttag").value

'***Event Log
    If erNo = "" Then erNo = 0
    If IsMissing(erMsg) = True Then erMsg = ""
    If IsMissing(strDatum) = True Then strDatum = ""
    If Len(strPreamble) < 2 Then strPreamble = "[None]"

'Fixxed - Syntax Error for Some Odd Reason! Apr 27th
If ((strTag = Empty) And (strForm = "fInvMain")) Then strTag = Screen.ActiveForm.txtTag 'Attempt to add tag# to entry
strStatus = cleanString(strStatus)
strDatum = cleanString(strDatum)
strComment = cleanString(strComment)

strSQL = "INSERT INTO tEvents(txtdate, myerrno, interrno, myerrmsg, interrmsg, txtform, stack, process, Datum, idLink) VALUES ('" & Now() & "','" & intType & "','" & erNo & "','" & strStatus & "','" & strComment & "','" & strForm & "','" & strErrStack & "','" & pXname & "','" & strDatum & "','" & strTag & "');"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

Exit Function

err_hand:
If Err.Number = 2475 Then
    bEcho = False
    Resume reS
    Else: MsgBox "555: CStatus Internal Error, Turn off error handling to view"
    End If


End Function
```

I need a boolean true or false IF form is active. If it isn't, I can't put stuff into a textbox in that.

Answer (score 0):

To determine if a particular form is open then set focus to form:

```
If CurrentProject.AllForms("finvmain").IsLoaded 
    strForm = "finvmain"
Elseif CurrentProject.AllForms("fclips").IsLoaded Then 
    strForm = "fclips"
End If
If strForm <> "" Then DoCmd.SelectObject acForm, strForm
```